# error Your credentials aren't allowed in django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 google sigin from android

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, google-signin, django-socialauth

i have installed Django `social-auth-app-django==3.1.0` for Django web for google sign in (working fine)

but

in same project i installed `django-rest-framework-social-oauth2` (doc has only facebook example) to client android app to google sigin(firebase) when user click google sigin in button in android it show available google email accounts and got the id_token() now i need to convert id_token to access token but i am getting error

i verified my id_token using this user

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=
```

(working fine)

[postman tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0SMp.png)
[admin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q2Jf.jpg)

error is

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "Your credentials aren't allowed"
}
```

and i searched entire google(3 days) to find solution i think one of the difficult taskadding google sigin in  `django rest frame work`

Comment: i appreciate solution to proceed next other wise i need to proceed with user name and password(1970s model) concept in djnago drf

Comment: problem is i need to update client id and sercet key in application model instead of default one and i need to pass access token instead of id token. at last it is very complicated to handle refresh token from google and refresh token in django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 lib so i just moved to simple token authentication system

Comment: It's possible the access_token from Google has expired. Do further testing on the google playground, `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/`. Under `Step 1: Select & authorize APIs`, choose Google oAuth2 API to test, you can use the access token in Step 3 to test with your local API